# trouble using animate.translationXBy() function in android studio

Tags: android-studio, animation, translation

I have written this code:

```
puckImg.animate().translationXBy(100).setDuration(300);
puckImg.animate().translationXBy(30).setDuration(2000);
puckImg.animate().translationXBy(90).setDuration(5000);
```

I am expecting my image view (puckImg) to first move by 100 in 300ms and then by another 30 for 2s and then another 90 for 5s.
but all that is happening is it is moving only by 90 for 5s. I am just not able to understand why that is happening. please help me.
is there any other way to do this step transition?

Comment: Anyone please answer

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> ```
> translationXBy
> Added in API level 12
>
> public ViewPropertyAnimator translationXBy (float value)
> This method will cause the View's translationX property to be animated by the specified value. 
>
> Animations already running on the property will be canceled.
> ```

As you can see, any animations running will be overridden by the latest animation of that same type. That's why only your last line of code is being run.
The code gets executed all at once, it doesn't wait 300 miliseconds and then goes to the next line.
You can use animation listener to execute what you want.